# java instanceof not finding method

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a problem with java instanceof. I have a class called Employee and several others that extend this one, for example - Manager. I also created another class,EmployeeStockPlan,  where I wanted to test if instanceof is finding which object I am using. But when I am calling a method from the new class, I have this error: The method `grantStock(Manager)` is undefined for the type `Loader`. Sorry, I am somehow new to some thing in java, I hope I am not asking dumb questions.

The Employee class:

```
package com.example.domain;

public class Employee {

private int empId;
private String name;
private String ssn;
private double salary;

public Employee(int empId, String name, String ssn, double salary) { // constructor
                                                                        // method;
    this.empId = empId;
    this.name = name;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.salary = salary;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    if (newName != null) {
        this.name = newName;
    }
}

public void raiseSalary(double increase) {
    this.salary += increase;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public String getDetails() { 

    return "Employee id: " + empId + "\n" + "Employee name: " + name;


}
```

}

The Manager class:

```
package com.example.domain;

public class Manager extends Employee {

    private String deptName;

        public Manager(int empId, String name, String ssn, double salary, String dept) {
        super(empId, name, ssn, salary);

    this.deptName = dept;
}

public String getDeptName() {
    return deptName;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return super.getDetails() + "\n" + 
            "Department: " + deptName;
}
```

}

The EmployeeStockPlan class:

```
package com.example.domain;

public class EmployeeStockPlan {

         public void grantStock(Employee e) {

                // nothing calculated, just simulating;
        System.out.println("This is an employee!");

    if (e instanceof Manager) {
        // process Manager stock grant
        System.out.println("This is a manager!");
    } else {
        // error - instance of Engineer?
        System.out.println("Not an engineer!");
    }
    return;
}
```

}

The main class:

```
 EmployeeStockPlan esp = new EmployeeStockPlan();
  Manager m = new Manager (12421, "Manager1", "111-4254-521", 2430, "Marketing1");
  grantStock(m);
```

Comment: That should be `esp.grantStock(m);`

Comment: 'instanceof' doesn't 'find methods'. You have a basic misunderstanding somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
EmployeeStockPlan esp = new EmployeeStockPlan();
Manager m = new Manager (12421, "Manager1", "111-4254-521", 2430, "Marketing1");
grantStock(m);
```

You have to call the `grantStock()` method on the `EmployeeStockPlan` object, otherwise Java is going to look for it in the main class, which doesn't have that method.

```
esp.grantStock(m);
```

Comment: duplicated anwser by me, you are faster :) +1 then

Comment: @X-Pippes It's not a duplicate of your answer. Yours falsely claimed that he needed to create an instance of a class that he was already instantiating.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much, Jesper!